# Is there a way to uninstall Cygwin B20?

Tags: cygwin

I want to uninstall Cygwin B20 from my computer but I keep getting this error:

```
Unable to locate the installation log file
'c:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\Uninst.isu'. Uninstallation will not continue.
```

Screenshot: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ7dU.jpg)

I don't remember having a cygnus folder when I was downloading cygwin and it's not located in my C drive. I can't seem to find the Uninst.isu file anywhere either. Is there another way to uninstall Cygwin B20?

Comment: I use Cygwin, but I had never heard of "B20".  With a bit of Googling, I found an [announcement for Cygwin B20.1](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/cygwin/1998-12/msg00093.html)  from 1998. Apparently you have a *very* old Cygwin installation. The installation procedure changed almost completely some time after that. Most people aren't going to be familiar with the very old version you're trying to uninstall. (Speculation: If you have no `C:\cygnus` folder, it's likely you've uninstalled it as much as you'll be able to.)

Comment: How did you even end up with an installation of such an old version of Cygwin?  You're probably fine to just delete the directory.